# Does PDO::bindParam / bindValue throw an exception if the data type is different from the supplied?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

It is my understanding that when using PDO::bindParam / bindValue while explicitly declaring a data type, an exception will be thrown if the data type is different from the supplied value.

*Excerpt from db class used to connect to a mysql database*

```
public function insert($sql, $values){
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    foreach($values as $value){
        $stmt->bindValue($value[1], $value[2], $value[3]);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
}

$array = array(
    0 => array(
        1 => ':jotName',
        2 => 'some jot string',
        3 => PDO::PARAM_STR

    )
);

$iSql = "INSERT INTO `jots`(`jotContext`) VALUES (:jotName)";

$con = new sql();
try{
    $con->insert($iSql,$array);
} catch(PDOException $exception) {
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}
```

I.e. If PDO::PARAM_STR was change to PDO::PARAM_INT in $array[0][3] the mysql transaction would fail because $array[0][2] is a string not an int.

I've tested this code block using PDO::PARAM_STR, PDO::PARAM_INT, & PDO::PARAM_BOOL. While I expected _STR to function correctly and insert a new record into the database. I was not expecting _BOOL & _INT to not throw an exception when calling the insert method.

Comment: This might change if you are using `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`, but mysql or php will generally cast parameters if they can. I would guess that is what's happening. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

Comment: It may be typecasting instead of verifying. Did you check the sql to see if the values were actually... correct? Like some jot string turning into zero.

Comment: @bassxzero - `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` are the only attributes set.

Comment: @IncredibleHat - Regardless of what data type is specified, `some jot string` is added to the database.

Comment: @Jaxchief That is fine. What I'm saying is that if you do set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`. then PHP will do the casting. If you don't, then MySQL will do the casting. Either way, I believe it's a casting problem.

Comment: I don't think it even gives errors if you try to stuff a `string` into an `int` defined column either. It just casts and stuffs as it can (haha). Are you WANTING it to throw errors if the types are wrong? Or just myffed that its not and looking for some form of confirmation of results seen?

Comment: @IncredibleHat  - "myffed that its not and looking for some form of confirmation of results seen?" Exactly. I was always under the impression when using the mysql/mariadb drive, if you specified a datatype and gave it a different datatype, the world would come to an end.

Comment: @Jaxchief Sometimes, I really wish it did! There has been times I accidentally was sticking a string into an int, and a whole textarea into an enum (hay, drunken late night coding has its results)... some immediate errors thrown would have saved some more hours of head scratching ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least for mysql - no, it will never throw an error.

Moreover, [99.99% of time mysql is happy with PDO::PARAM_STR](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#methods) for any type. Therefore, you can simplify your insert function dramatically, omitting all the unnecessary stuff from the $values array:

```
public function insert($sql, $values){
    return $this->connect()->prepare($sql)->execute($values);
}
$array = array('jotName' => 'some jot string');
$db->insert($sql, $array);
```

Comment: So my question now turns to what is the point of PDO::PARAM_x. I.e. my logic would be, get data, validate / sanitize data, bind data, execute. While I understand what @bassxzero was saying about type casting. How can you typecast a string to a int.

Comment: There is not that much point, but a few edge cases where it could be useful, [INT for example](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#limit)